# Determine the value of k so that the following system is consistent.find solution for these values of k.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

$[(3w+2x+4y+0z=3),(0w+x+y+z=k),(5w+4x+6y+0z=15)]$. I first used elementary row operation. Then $k$ seems to be taking any value for system to be consistent. I'm not sure of its correct and if it is how do l find for the values of $k$.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, with consistent you mean, you search for values for $k$ such that the system has at least one solution. Then you are right. For any $w,x,y, k$ you can choose $z=k-x-y$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.